# cassandra map, Cannot decode string as UTF8:

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to store binary data to the Cassandra DB, here is the description

```
CREATE TABLE first.block (
        uuid text PRIMARY KEY,
        data map<bigint, blob>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'class':         'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
        AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I am trying to save data on the blob type, But when attempting to write for the C driver for Cassandra, I am getting error  Cannot decode string as UTF8:,
I believe for blob type there needs to be no validation since it is Byte Type.
I am very new to Cassandra, Please help,
Thank you

Comment: Please add your insert statement to your question. You are aware that you should "_Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying because Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety._" (from [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html))?

Comment: Actually, post the c code you are using to insert the data. You should also consider using a UUID type for your primary key.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, The problem was that i was trying to treat the insert query in some old SQL fashion , once I made use of cass_statement_bind_collection() method. The problem seems to be solved.